# JQuery DatePicker broke anchore tag in Laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I need to call a view in a Laravel Controller, with parameters and with Anchor Tag. I do this with the following code ant it's works fine:

```
return Redirect::route('editplan',
    ['patient' => $patient,
    'plan' => $plan,'/#sectionFour' ]);
```

The problem was emerged when I added some field date on the the top of the page and used a datepicker, which I need, like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<label for="nome">Date Start</label>
 <input class="form-control date" type="text"
    value="{{ !empty($plan) && $plan->dateStart ? Carbon\Carbon::parse($plan->dateStart)->format('d/m/Y') : '' }}"
    name="dateStart" id="dateStart"/>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the blade page I have the following code, without it the anchor tag works fine. Adding it the page makes a small scroll to return to the head.

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $('.date').datepicker({
                firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                weekDayFormat: 'narrow',
                inputFormat: 'd/M/y',
                outputFormat: 'd/M/y',
                markup: 'bootstrap4',
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                modal: false
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

I need to use the datepicker, how can I fix the problem and get the anchor tag to work?

Comment: You can assign value in this way `$(".date").val("{{ !empty($plan) && $plan->dateStart ? Carbon\Carbon::parse($plan->dateStart)->format('d/m/Y') : '' }}");`

Comment: you think that the anchor tag does not works 
because of the way field value data is set? 
I tried the proposed solution but nothing changes. Accessing the page the anchor tag does not work.

Comment: I didn't see any anchor tag o your question

Comment: #sectionFour when i call the route. Whitout $('.date').datepicker it's work, with $('.date').datepicker does not work